# Does an accuracy of 97.55 % indicate an overfitted model?

Tags: machine-learning, logistic-regression, evaluation

I have implemented a logistic regression model in predicting high-risk claims. My model is giving an accuracy of 97%. Does that indicate that my model is overfitted?

Comment: It's not really possible to answer whether model is overfitted or not based on such little information. You should at least tell how many datapoints you have in each class in training, whether you used a separate tets set, what are the model's results on this test set if it was used.

Comment: No, overfitting isn't determined by looking at the raw accuracy, generally you need to use some form of [cross validation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_(statistics)). In any case, this isn't really an on-topic question for stack overflow, which is for *programming* questions, you probably want... [statistics.se]

Comment: @AlexanderPivovarov Sorry for missing out on the details. Yes, I have used a separate Test set. The response variable was highly imbalance so I oversampled the training set to get an equal distribution of the 2 classes. My training set has  213316 records and the Test set has 26703 records. My model got an accuracy of 97%, Recall of 94.24% and Precision of 99.9% on the test set.

Comment: Comments is *not* the place for providing such info; please edit & update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The accuracy in the training set is not enough for the overfitting. Are you using a validation set? If you are not using it, you should split your data set to three parts: Validation set, test set and training set. During the training, you should use training and validation set. If you have high accuarcy in training set and low accuracy in the validation set then your model is overfitting.